# Magento Redirect Homepage to some innerpage

Tags: magento, redirect

Currently i'm developing a ecommerce website using magento. I want to redirect the homepage to some inner page. I'm using rack space server so there is no cpanel access. If cpanel access is there we can easily redirect the pages using redirect option.

Is there any prebuild option in magento to redirect homepage to any inner pages?

Guide me magento experts..

Regards,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get you exactly. You can redirect in different ways according to your need

1. You can redirect the index page to inner page using .htaccess
2. To set a inner page as default home page, navigate to system>Configuration  >Web > Default Pages  and set  CMS Home Page.
3. Check this if you need to create a new landing page - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yoast/extension/1915/yoast-landing-pages